# WPF DataGrid CheckBox Check/Uncheck with single click

Tags: wpf

I need check and uncheck of CheckBox using spacebar key in a single click.I tried like below.

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Chk" MinWidth="40">      
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                            
<DataTemplate>                                
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SELECT,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="ChkSelect" 
Click="ChkSelect_Click" KeyDown="ChkSelect_KeyDown"/>                            
</DataTemplate>                        
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

With mouse I am able to check/uncheck in a single click.
But the same thing I am not able to do it with spacebar key.
The key down event is firing only when I press tab key twice.
How to achieve check/uncheck CheckBox in a single click using spacebar key?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [FocusManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager(v=vs.110).aspx).FocusedElement to your `checkbox` in order to focus the checkbox like:

```
     <CheckBox FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
     IsChecked="{Binding Path=SELECT,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
     Name="ChkSelect" Click="ChkSelect_Click" KeyDown="ChkSelect_KeyDown"/>
```

**EDIT:**

Add `CellEditingTemplate` with cellTemplate too like:

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SELECT,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="ChkSelect" Click="ChkSelect_Click" KeyDown="ChkSelect_KeyDown"/>     
  </DataTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

when you enter edit mode on your `DataGrid` you will get focus on this check box whenever your reach the cell containing it (using tab).

**EDIT 2:**

You can also Try [DataGridCheckBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcheckboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DataGridTemplateColumn`, which is used for checkboxes only. Example:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Chk" Binding="{Binding Path=SELECT,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I added above mentioned FocusManager.FocusedElement in xaml.But still I am not able to check/uncheck the CheckBox using the spacebar.

Comment: try removing `KeyDown` event from checkbox

Comment: Hi Shaminder,I tried like that.But still I am unable to do check/uncheck with  spacebar key.

Comment: @user5668833 you can also try `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` instead of `DataGridTemplateColumn`. as mentioned in the edited answer

Comment: Still my issue is not resolved.No action happening when I press space bar key.I tried with all the options informed by you.But I don't understand why event is not firing.